# Installing Entity Framework 6 with NuGet Package Manager does not create the relevant references. (I think)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reference

I am following the "Getting Started with Entity Framework 6" tutorial by Julie Lerman on Pluralsight.

In the 4th video of module 2, she instructs to download the Entity Framework package from the NuGet Package Manager.
When she does this:

1. The relevant reference is added to the project.
2. An "App.config" file is created.

When I do this none of that happens.

When I try to inherit DbContext (which is what she does next), I get these errors:

CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) NinjaDomain.DataModel   C:\Learn\Ninja.Demo\NinjaDomain.DataModel\Class1.cs 6   Active

CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  NinjaDomain.DataModel   C:\Learn\Ninja.Demo\NinjaDomain.DataModel\Class1.cs 2   Active

The code that generates these errors:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace NinjaDomain.DataModel
{
    public class NinjaContext : DbContext
    {
    }
}
```

The words "Entity" from the 2nd line and "DbContext" from the 6th line are red-squiggled.

I am using Visual Studio 2019, while she is using Visual Studio 2015, which I assume to be the problem.

[This is what my solution looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6qJV.png)

Help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was lack of attention on my part. When creating the project, I chose "Class Library (.NET Standard)" instead of "Class Library (.NET Framework)".